# Cannot convert return expression of type '[(key: String, value: Int)]' to return type '[String : Int]'

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a custom data struct that looks like this:

```
struct Entitlements {
    var entitlements: [Entitlement]

    struct Entitlement {
        var type: String
        var entitlement: Int
    }
}
```

I have an initialiser that takes a dictionary of [String: Int] and maps it to [Entitlement]:

```
init(entitlements: [String: Int]) {
    self.entitlements = entitlements.map({ (entitlement) -> Entitlement in
        return Entitlement(type: entitlement.key, entitlement: entitlement.value)
    })
}
```

I also have a function that maps [Entitlement] to [String: Int]. I have attempted to write it like this:

```
func simplify() -> [String: Int] {
    self.entitlements.map { (entitlement) -> (key: String, value: Int) in
        return (key: entitlement.type, value: entitlement.entitlement)
    }
}
```

But I get an error that looks like this:

> 'Cannot convert return expression of type '[(key: String, value: Int)]' to return type '[String : Int]''

I have tried using flatmap to combine dictionaries into one but with no success:

```
func simplify() -> [String: Int] {
    self.entitlements.flatMap { (entitlement) -> [String: Int] in
        return [entitlement.type, entitlement.entitlement]
}
}
```

But I get an error:

> 'Unable to infer closure type in the current context'

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:) and map the entitlements array to an array of tuples to get the correct input format for the init.

```
func simplify() -> [String: Int] {
   Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: entitlements.map{ ($0.type, $0.entitlement) })
}
```

If you need to handle duplicate keys there is also a variant that takes a closure for handling what to do. Here is an example based on Apples doc where the first key is always selected

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: Int] {
    Dictionary(entitlements.map { ($0.type, $0.entitlement) },
               uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first })
}
```